# how does ostream& reference automatically created?

Tags: c++

In an overloaded `operator<<()` function in a class that uses it, it will be used in the main() function like

```
int main()
{
  MyOwnClass myClass;
  cout << myClass;

}
```

how was the << operator able to create ostream& reference
and can we do it like

```
operator<<(myClass);
```

because it is a friend function

Comment: `cout << myClass;` is merely the same as a function call `operator<<(cout,myClass)`. Do you have any particular problems?

Comment: I was thinking of something like `cout.operator<<(myClass);` thanks help me clear my mind

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In theory, it could also be a function call `cout.operator<<(myClass)` (though of course not with `cout`).

Comment: @Walter It's what it is, and you explained that in your answer well.

Answer (score 1):

You must overload the **output stream operator** `std::ostream& << myclass`. A binary operator, such as `<<` can either be implemented as a member of its first operand type (and taking the second operand as only argument) or as a standalone function taking both operands as arguments.

Here, only the second option is possible, since you cannot change the definition of `std::ostream`. For example

```
struct myclass // just an example
{
  int data;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, myclass const&obj)
{
  return os << obj.data;
}
```

Inside the function body, this calls the `operator<<(std::ostream&, int)`, which is defined in `iostream` and returns the reference to the same `ostream` that it received on input. In case of a more complicated class, you can just return the stream.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, myclass const&obj)
{
  for(auto x:obj.table)
    os << std::setprecision(12) << x
  return os;
}
```